# Problema al definir variables en un ChatBot

Tags: javascript

Estoy desarrollando un módulo para una página web. que trata sobre asesoría en línea. Es por eso que estoy creando un *chatBot* con respuestas programadas basadas en palabras clave solicitadas por un cliente. Entonces uso *JavaScript* donde uso un `switch`. Declaro variables y les asigno su valor que sería la respuesta para cada caso.

El problema es que les doy su valor, pero cuando voy a mi sitio web y hago una pregunta incluyendo  la palabra clave, me sale el `undefined`, cuando de hecho sí está definido. Luego hago la misma pregunta repetidamente hasta que muestra lo que configuré para esa variable, y entonces sucede que a veces lo muestra y otras no.

Quiero saber de qué se trata.

Esto solo sucede con los casos 6, 7 y 8, son de la misma manera que los anteriores, pero no sé por qué a veces se muestran esos mensajes.

Dejaré el código *JavaScript*:

```js
//Declaración de variables
var cadena, cod, respuesta;

//Declaración de expresiones
var tener = RegExp("(TIENE|TIENES|TENGO|TENÉS|TENES)");
var edad = /AÑOS/;
var saludar = RegExp("(HOLA|QUE TAL)");
var bien = RegExp("(BIEN)");
var laptop = RegExp("(LAPTOP|ORDENADOR|COMPUTADOR|COMPUTADORA|NOTEBOOK|PC)");
var programador = RegExp("(PROGRAMADOR)");
var mediano = RegExp("(MEDIANO)");
var alto = RegExp("(ALTO)");


function evaluarExpresion() {
 cadena = document.getElementById("txtPregunta").value;
 escribirChat(cadena);
 cadena = cadena.toUpperCase();
 document.getElementById("txtPregunta").value="";
 cod=0;

 /*
 document.getElementById("resultado1").innerHTML= tener.test(cadena);
 document.getElementById("resultado2").innerHTML= edad.test(cadena);
 */ 
 if (saludar.test(cadena)==true) {
  cod = 1;
 };
 if (bien.test(cadena)==true) {
  cod = 2;
 };
 if (tener.test(cadena)==true && edad.test(cadena)==true ) {
  cod = 4;
 }; 
 if (laptop.test(cadena)==true  ) {
  cod = 5;
 }; 
 if (programador.test(cadena)==true ) {
  cod = 6;
 };
 if (mediano.test(cadena)==true ) {
  cod = 7;
 };
 if (alto.test(cadena)==true ) {
  cod = 8;
 };

 //Lama a responder
 setTimeout(responder, 1000);
 //responder();
}

function responder() {
 var r = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
 console.log("random " + r);
 console.log("cod " + cod);
 var mensaje;
 switch (cod) {
 case 1:
 if (r == 1) {
 mensaje = "Hola!!! Que tal?";
 };
 if (r == 2) {
 mensaje = "hola ¿como estas?";
 };
 if (r == 3) {
 mensaje = "hola ¿como te va?";
 };

 break;

 case 2:
 mensaje = "Me alegra mucho!!! ¿en que podemos ayudarte?";
 break;

 case 4:
 if (r == 1) {
 mensaje = "Es una pregunta muy personal";
 };
 if (r == 2) {
 mensaje = "Demasiado joven para ti";
 };
 if (r == 3) {
 mensaje = "Tengo toda la edad que te puedas imaginar!!";
 };

 break;

 case 5:
 if (r == 1) {
 mensaje = " deseas un ordenador . Que rol desempeñas";
 };
 if (r == 2) {
 mensaje = "un computador y  ¿A que te dedicas?";
 };
 if (r == 3) {
 mensaje = "Una notebook . ok ¿A que profesion te dedicas?";
 };
 break;

 case 6:
 if (r == 1) {
 mensaje = " tenemos lo mejor para ustedes los programadores ¿Deseas algo de pecio alto o mediano costo? ";
 };
 break;

 case 7:
 if (r == 1) {
 mensaje = " Mediano costo : Laptop con procesador core I5 8gb RAM 1.000 dolares ";
 };
 break;

 case 8:
 if (r == 1) {
 mensaje = " Alto costo : Laptop con procesador core I7 16gb RAM 2.500 dolares ";
 };
 break;
 default:
 mensaje = "No entiendo lo que me estás diciendo";

 }
 //document.getElementById("respuesta").innerHTML = mensaje;
 escribirChat(mensaje);
}

function escribirChat (texto) {
 document.getElementById("areaChat").innerHTML += texto + "\r";
}
```

```html
<div><textarea disabled style="width: 400px; height: 100px"  id="areaChat" ></textarea>
<div>
  <input id="txtPregunta" />
  <button onclick="evaluarExpresion()" >Enviar</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Hice una edición en la pregunta sin cambiar la esencia del código. Me gustaría que pruebes el _snippet_ y me digas si el problema persiste. Quizás la pregunta se deba cerrar por ser un error de sintáxis.

Answer (score 0):

El problema entiendo que es que `r` es un número random de 1 a 3, en los cases 6,7 y 8 se asigna el valor de `mensaje` cuando `r` es igual a 1 en otro caso daría `undefined`. Para solucionarlo puedes o bien agregar los casos 2 y 3 o bien poner un else de manera de que siempre `mensaje` tenga un valor. De cualquier manera deberías definir `mensaje` antes `let mensaje = ""`.

```
    case 6:
        if (r == 1) {
          mensaje = " tenemos lo mejor para ustedes los programadores ¿Deseas algo de pecio alto o mediano costo? ";
        } 
        else {
          mensaje = " Otra cosa ";
        }
    ;
        break;
```